# Ignore Form.ShowDialog() when testing a button click event that pops up a form?

Tags: winforms, nunit

I would like to ask how you would test a button click event where by you want to check the results after having shown a form. I am using NUnit to test. I created an extension method to show the form as below,have tried different methods such as checking Debugger.IsAttached?;

```
    public static void ShowFormDialog(this Form form)
    {
        if(Debugger.IsAttached)
            form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

but this appears to still popup the form while running my test. Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: This code makes me feel sick. Why on Earth are you using an extension method? What are you trying to test here? Are you testing the form or something else? Please post some more code in order to clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your design might need some work. What are you testing ? The form or the class that handles the form events? If those two are not separated, it should be.

If the latter, then you should use dependency injection, so you can stub the form, and raise the event in your own way.

Using conditionals like Debugger.IsAttached should never be used without extremely good reasons (haven't seen a good enough reason yet).

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I have refactored my code by removing all the bad code within my events and extracted them into a controller class,which is then testable. The difficult though is figuring out a way to mock out a MessageBox,because what happens is that I run my test on a method containing a call to a MessageBox to display a simple message,and this pops up and hangs my test. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad you could use my answer. MessageBoxes in code is hell on unittests. I usually wrap messagehandling in a class, and inject it just like the form - and yes, by now you probably guessed that I love injection :o)